# I want to print my data on html that is stored in excel sheet(xlsx), actually i am getting output but it is not in a proper way . please check code

Tags: django, excel

```
          Views.py
```

info = []
def get_info(request):

```
r1 = pd.read_excel('file_data.xlsx')
for index, row in r1.iterrows():
        if row["USER NAME"] == str(user_name()):
           info.append(row)
           #name = row['USER NAME']
           #date = row['DATE']
           #file_name = row['FILE NAME']
           #remarks = row['REMARKS']
           
           
return render(request,'files.html',{'info':info})

#return render(request,'files.html',{'name':name, 'date':date, 'file_name':file_name, 'remarks':remarks, 'info':info})

       
         output
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iULDA.png)

I need to print data in corresponding fields but it coming only in single field in list format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your template, you should use something like this inside your table:

```
{% for row in info %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{ row.field1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.field2 }}</td>
      <td>{{ row.field3 }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: first of all Thank you for the response, I tried for loop also but that time they are coming one by one vertically not in a table manner